# Get r_basicprofile vanityName

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get user profile link with LinkedIn API, and here is what I get :

```
firstName:"..."
formattedName: "..."
id: "..."
lastName: "..."
pictureUrl: "..."
email: "..."
firstName: "..."
first_name: "..."
formattedName: "..."
id: "..."
lastName: "..."
last_name: "..."
name: "..."
pictureUrl: "..."
thumbnail: "..."
```

in the doc it says that in basicprofile I should get vanityName but it's not there ?
How can I get the user profile link ?

Comment: It does not say it over here - https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile. Can you share the link of the documentation?

Comment: Sure : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/profile/basic-profile

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am trying to get headline.

Here is the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile